# doCmd.openreport where clause prompting

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a simple piece of code written to open a report.

```
  Private Sub FormButton_Enter()
    Dim strwhere As String
    strwhere = Me.FormText
    DoCmd.Openreport "rtpname",acViewPreview,,"ColumnName=" & strwhere 
  End Sub
```

I am getting two popups , even though i pass the filter criteria from the form. Please advice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One potential cause is that `ColumnName` is non-numeric and you are not putting the value in quotes.  If this the problem then the fix is:

```
 DoCmd.Openreport "rtpname",acViewPreview,,"ColumnName='" & strwhere & "'"
```

Comment: I can't quite figure out why this answer works. Leaving out quotes for a text field shouldn't result in a parameter prompt, just a data type mismatch.

Comment: @Fenton: Because it interpreted the value as an expression that it expected to refer either to a field on an open form or a column in the query behind "rptname".  Since it couldn't evaluate that expression, it prompted for a value for it, and then it prompted for a value for the original "ColumnName".